# Select multiple value for layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filter

On the category page (frontend) I'd like to select multiple value. For example if I select the color blue, then the filter 'Color' will be removed from the left side of the screen.

I'd like to keep the filter visible even if I select it so that I can select let say another color (or mutliple sizes or brands..), without installing any extension.

Thing is I never worked with layered filter that much before in Magento so I don't know where to start and what to look for.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: you want apply filter for multiple values of same attribute?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to select let's say 2 colors or more (or sizes or brands...). But I can't because default Magento behaviour is to hide the filter once you select a value.